# Accessing a global variable in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, global

I have written a recursive function that creates combinations of all possible results of a nx3 data where n is variable

the structure of a data point
[name_of_variable cluster_number uniqueness_condition]

```
from collections import defaultdict
x= [[1,1,'a'],[2,1,'b'],[3,1,'c'],[4,2,'c'],[5,2,'d'],[6,2,'a'],[7,3,'a'],[8,3,'d']]
c=defaultdict(list)
for i in x:
    c[i[1]]+=[i]
w=list()
def rec_cal(i,lis):
    if i in c.keys():
        for j in c[i]:
            lis.append(j[0])
            rec_cal(i+1,lis)
            lis.pop()
    else:
        global w
        w.append(lis)##print(lis)
rec_cal(1,[])
```

I am trying to store all the generated 3 pairs in w but in the end i get an empty list , where am i going wrong any help will be appreciated

p.s. if write print(lis) instead of w.append(lis) all the correct lists are printed .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `w.append(lis)` you append a reference to the list `lis`, not a copy of the list. Everything that you append into `lis` also gets popped out when the recursive function returns so all you will get in `w` will be a lot of references to the same empty list.

Also, don't do `i in c.keys()`, just do `i in c` and you aren't assigning a new value to `w`, so there's no need to use `global w`.

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
w[0] is w[1]
```

may help you understand why it's failing. The references you have appended all point to the same object.

Replacing

```
w.append(lis)
```

with

```
w.append(lis.copy())
```

is a quick fix. But be careful in general with mutating lists and referencing lists.